# Strict-Alternation Synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

I was wondering Could Strict-Alternative Method work on multi-core CPU?
for this purpose, I've written some code

```
int counter = 0;
int turn;
void producer()
{
    while(turn == 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    turn = 1;
}
void consumer()
{
    while(turn == 0);
    // Slip 
    turn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        counter--;
    }
    // it should be here (turn = 0;)

}
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (counter == 0)
    {
        i++;
        thread t1, t2;

        t2 = thread(consumer);
        t1 = thread(producer);

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        cout << i << " " << counter << endl;

    }
    cout << i << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

first of all, I've tried to run this code without this slip thinking that if that code runs on multi-core CPU it should be a moment when turn variable is changed before it should be due to memory reordering happened by CPU or compiler making the 2 threads to be inside the CS and hence causing data inconsistency, but after running thousands of iterations this does not happen!
ok, I thought that I must be running on a single core! so I have made this little slip (you can say I have made memory-reordering deliberately)
if they are running on a single core it should come a time when turn variable is assigned to 0 in consumer and the thread gets preempted allowing another thread to enter CS before it finishes and hence causes a data inconsistency, but after about 67000 iterations this does not happen either!

Comment: You have memory barriers here, so the threads might not observe any changes made by another. Note also that the compiler is free to assume that `turn` _never changes_ and emit code accordingly. Consider using `std::atomic<int>` for your shared variables.

Comment: I don't know too much about that concept Memory Fence or (barrier) I just know that compiler might do some reordering (for optimization reasons) and CPU too, so could you explain more, please! where is the memory barrier?

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. I meant you have _no_ memory barriers here, which creates the problem -- there is never an instruction for the compiler/CPU to re-read one of the values from system memory, so the compiler/CPU are free to assume that the values never change.